# How can I write php code in notepad++?

Tags: php, notepad++

I'm very new to this editor, and I want to know the basics of writing PHP code in notepad++ e.g which file should I create, and from which option?

Comment: Open a new document.   Write PHP code.    Save the new file as a .php file.

Comment: Please used notepad++ its good editor for lots of languages.Please google it..

Comment: @THE ONLY ONE: Of course he's using Notepad++ that's why he's asking this question.

Comment: He might be thinking about, like writing with full IDE behavior like in visual studio or install another plugin for IntelliSense for notepad++ etc.. this is why when I'm googling, this page is show up

Comment: A big part of Stack Overflow culture is demonstrating that you have done extensive research already but have hit a road block. Downvoted because you it is important to understand that you have to put some effort into finding a solution before resorting to using Stack Overflow as a free helpdesk, and you must prove that effort by describing links you checked and steps you took. If you look at most of my posts you will see a good format for structuring your questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, open Notepad++. Then open a new document if a new one is not on the screen already. Then go to the languages menu option, go down to P, and select PHP. Then type in your PHP code. When you want to save it, press the save button near the top right hand corner, and choose a name.

That's all. Pretty simple, eh?

Just note, other languages can be selected from the languages bar. If you select no languages, it would be default text, but that can be changed too, and after you save the file with a `.php` extension, Notepad++ will automatically recognise the document as PHP, and render it accordingly.

P.S. If all that seems a smidgen complicated, you might want to read bretterer's comment. It's exactly what you should do.

Comment: I couldn't even bring myself to write an answer.   It shows a FULL lack of knowledge and research.  A simple Google search would help.

Comment: I did googled it but did'nt find my answer thanks for your consideration :)